# how can we check through the api of hotmail that the user execite this email php

Tags: php

Hi
I want to check the email address of hotmail that the user write in text box.i check email address that address have the hotmail server or not.example newtest123@hotmail.com.check in the hotmail the newtest123 id is in hotmail database.

How to check this email address is really exists?

Comment: I think there is no working API for doing something like this. Its all about SPAM-concerns. If you can cheack, if an e-mail address exists, you can send spam.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to test to see if an e-mail exists.  The most common way to verify an e-mail address is to send an e-mail with a 1 time hash that you stored on in your database.  When the users receives teh e-mail they will click the link(to the one time hash) thus verify their email account.